# Forward only range IP through VPN

Tags: openvpn

I have established VPN using OpenVPN.
Ubuntu 14.04

Now, I want to forward through VPN only specific traffic, based on destination IP range (i.e 192.168.2.1 - 192.168.2.255).

Should I use iptables for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

You should only advertise routes to that IP range via the VPN. This is part of the VPN server setup and you should of covered it when setting up the VPN.

[https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans] shows how you'd add the routes for some lans behind the VPN.

Like so:

```
route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

Also make sure you *don't* have

```
redirect-gateway
```

As this causes all traffic to try and route over your VPN.